# Swift existential types: how to create generic Views that conform to a protocol?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am building a SwiftUI macOS app that manipulates a set of views ("playgrounds"). Each playground has some specific info but all share a generic common View. I also want an enum to list all available views in my app.

I struggle with Swift existential types and protocol to model my data structures. In particular, I always end up with the error "**Type any View can not conform to protocol View**" Despite having read many docs and blog posts on existential types and why a protocol can not conform to itself. I am blocked on this.

Here is my code :

```swift
// the protocol all my playgrounds must implement
protocol PlaygroundComponent {
    associatedtype Body: View
    @ViewBuilder var component: Self.Body { get }
}

// a generic type that implements the common part of all the playgrounds + the specific part from subtypes
struct PlaygroundView<Content: PlaygroundComponent>: View {
    let content : Content
    var body: some View {
        Text("reused content")
        content.component
    }
}

// a concrete playground, it defines only the specific part 
struct ListModelsPlayground: PlaygroundComponent {
    var component: some View {
        Text("ListModelsPlayground")
    }
}

// an enum that lists all the implementations I have (only one to keep this example short)
enum Playgrounds  {
    case listModels
    var info: any PlaygroundView<PlaygroundComponent> { ListModelsPlayground() } // ---> compilation error : Type 'any PlaygroundComponent' cannot conform to 'PlaygroundComponent'
}
```

How can I model a generic view with individual subcomponents to later be part of such structure or `List( ForEach { } )` SwiftUI views ?

Comment: Don't plan on using existentials with SwiftUI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `PlaygroundComponent` is just reinventing `View`. You don't need it. If the playground components have some common properties that you want to model, that's *data*, and they don't belong in the view. If each playground has its own unique properties, that's its `@State`.

As an example, let's implement two playgrounds *views*:

```
struct ListModelsPlayground: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("ListModelsPlayground")
    }
}

struct AnotherPlayground: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Another Playground")
    }
}
```

Now let's say you want an enum so that you can put these playgrounds into an array, and display them in a `List` or something. That's *data*, and that's where the common properties of `PlaygroundComponent`s go.

```
enum Playground: Identifiable, CaseIterable {
    case listModels
    case another
    
    var id: Playground { self }
    
    // let's suppose each playground has a title property, as an example
    var title: String {
        switch self {
        case .listModels: return "List Models"
        case .another: return "Another"
        }
    }
    // if you have more common properties,
    // perhaps bundle them all into a struct
}
```

Note that if the common properties can change, you should use a `struct` instead, with `static let`s representing each type of playground.

Now we can display the array `Playground.allCases` in a `List`, and perhaps in a `NavigationSplitView`, so that clicking on one of them goes to a `PlaygroundView`.

```
@State var selectedPlayground: Playground?

var body: some View {
    NavigationSplitView {
        List(Playground.allCases, selection: $selectedPlayground) { playground in
            Text(playground.title)
        }
    } detail: {
        if let selectedPlayground {
            PlaygroundView(component: selectedPlayground)
        }
    }

}
```

Notice how `PlaygroundView` just takes a `playground`. That's really all it needs - the *data*. It can use it to decide which playground to show.

```
struct PlaygroundView: View {
    let component: Playground // make this a @Binding if the playground view can change the common properties
    var body: some View {
        Text("reused content")
        switch component {
        case .listModels: ListModelsPlayground()
        case .another: AnotherPlayground()
        }
    }
}
```

If you really don't like that `switch`, you can extract it to the enum as a property:

```
@ViewBuilder
var view: some View {
    switch self {
    case .listModels: ListModelsPlayground()
    case .another: AnotherPlayground()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This approach of composition vs inheritance works. I should have thought about that pattern before posting :-)  I marked your answer as valid and I will adopt this approach in my project. However, for my own understanding, I still wonder how an inheritance pattern would work. I understand Swift resolves types at compile time (vs Objective-C, Java, Python, Typescript) and that prevents using existential types. Is there a way to solve my problem through inheritance and protocols ?

Comment: I don't like the double use of a Switch but it seems the only way to avoid using existentials. The double use of switch statement in Playgrounds and Playgrounds seems against the "don't repeat your self" paradigm. 
But when I try to transform this PlaygroundView a generic I hit the error 'Type any View can not conform to protocol View'. Extracting it as you suggested to the enum itself if the cleanest option IMHO

Comment: @SébastienStormacq If you use a struct (with a private init and constants written as `static let`s) instead of an enum, you can put `title` as a stored property, hence removing one switch. Of course, there needs to be extra property indicating which type of playground it is, and the `Identifiable` conformance needs to change, which means you would use a different type for the `List` selection. The code needs a few changes, but it is doable with a struct too.